# Fixed header positioning in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, positioning, fixed

Trying to mess with this Imbalance wordpress theme http://wpshower.com/demo/?theme=imbalance and having fixed the positioning of the header I can't figure out why the main page gallery is scrolling over the header on all browsers. Any help would be very appreciated http://www.pensandneedles.co.uk

*note: I've hidden the gallery on the home page until i can correct this*

.css stylesheet

```
*/
body {
background-color:#FFF;
line-height:1.4 !important;}

a:link, a:visited {

text-decoration:underline;


color:#002C57;}
a:hover {


color:#F23B35;}
#outer {
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#000;
font-size:12px;
width:945px;
margin:0 auto;}
p {
margin-bottom:15px !important;}
blockquote {
font-style:italic !important;
margin-left:70px !important;}

table {border-collapse:separate;border-spacing:0;}
table, td, th {vertical-align:middle;}
table {margin-bottom:1.4em;width:100%;}
th {font-weight:bold;}
thead th {background:#FF3706;}
th, td, caption {padding:4px 10px 4px 5px;}
tr.even td {background:#FF3706;}
tfoot {font-style:italic;}
td#next {text-align:right;}
caption {background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #EEEEEE;}
th, td, caption {padding:4px 10px 4px 5px;}
caption, th, td {font-weight:strong;text-align:left;}


#top {
height: 85px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-top:27px;}
#logo {
/*  background-attachment: scroll;
background-image: url(images/logo.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: left top;*/


height: 90px;
width: 600px;}
#logo a {

position:fixed;
margin-left:295px;

display:block;

height: 95px;
width: 345px;


border-bottom:solid 1px #F23B35;}



#menu {
position:fixed;
margin-left:340px;
margin-top:-90px;
width:100%x;
display:block;

height: 0px;
text-color:red;}

#menu #navicons {


width:237px;
height:50px;
float:right;}
#menu #navicons li {

float:right;}
#menu #navicons a {
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
padding-left:20px;
background-image: url(images/top-icons.png);
background-attachment: scroll;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:0 7px;
text-decoration:none !important;
font-size:11px;
display:block;}
#menu #navicons a:hover {
background-image: url(images/top-icons-hover.png);}
#menu #navicons a#subscribe {}
#menu #navicons a#twitter {
background-position: left -19px;}
#menu #navicons a#facebook {
background-position: left -58px;}


#cats {
padding-left: 10px;}
#cats li {
float: left;
line-height: 50px;
margin-right: 25px;}
#cats li a {
float: left;
line-height: 50px;
text-decoration:none !important;}
#cats li a:hover, #cats li a.active {
border-bottom:solid 1px #ff3706;}
#categories, #archives, #search {
width:945px;
overflow:hidden;
padding:0;
border-bottom:solid 1px #ff3706;}
#categories ul li, #archives ul li {
font-size:11px;
float:left;
width:293px;
padding:0px;
line-height:20px;
height:20px;}
#categories ul li a, #archives ul li a {
text-decoration:none !important;
display:block;
width:293px;
height:20px;
border-top:solid 1px #FFF;
border-bottom:solid 1px #FFF;
padding:0 10px;}
#categories ul li a span, #archives ul li a span {
float:right;}
#categories ul li a:hover, #archives ul li a:hover {
border-top:solid 1px #FF3706;
border-bottom:solid 1px #FF3706;}
#main {
overflow:hidden;}
#error {
font-size:21px;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:1.2;
margin:15px 15px 45px 15px;}
.li_container {


padding-top:80px;}
#categories .li_container, #archives .li_container {
padding-top:0px;}
li.article {
margin-bottom:15px;

position:relative;}
.li_cont1, .li_cont2 {
margin-right:15px;}
.mcol2 {
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;}
#categories .li_container ul, #archives .li_container ul {}
.article ul, .article ol {



margin-bottom:15px;
list-style:square inside none;}

.single .article ul, .single .article ol {
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left: 165px;
list-style:square inside none;}

.single .article ul ul, .single .article ol ol, 
.single .article ul ul ul, .single        .article ol ol ol{
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left: 30px;
list-style:square inside none;}
.article ul {
list-style:square inside none;}

.article ul ul, .article ul ul ul {


margin-left: 15px;}

.article ol {
list-style-type: decimal;}
.article img {
/*margin-bottom:15px;*/}

.article p a, .commentlist p a {
border-bottom:1px solid #FF3706;
text-decoration:none;}
.article p a:hover, .commentlist p a:hover {
border-bottom: 1px solid;
text-decoration:none;
color: #FF3706;}
li.article .postmetadata {
color:#555;
font-size:11px;
margin-top:20px;}
li.article .postmetadata a {
color:#FF3706 !important;}
li.article h2 {
font-size:21px;
line-height:1.2;
margin-bottom:15px;
font-weight:normal;}
li.article h2 a {
text-decoration:none !important;}
.preview {
position:relative;}
.article-over {

position:absolute;



left:0;
top:0;
padding:15px;}

.article .article-over {
display:none;}



#sidebar ul, #sidebar ol {
margin-left: 0px;}

#sidebar .article:hover img, .li_container .article:hover img {
filter:alpha(opacity=10);
opacity: 0.1;
/* -moz-opacity:0.1; */}
.article:hover .article-over {
display:block;}
.single #sidebar {
width:305px;
padding-left:30px;
float:right;
padding-bottom:15px;
padding-top:15px;}
.single #sidebar h2 {
font-size:17px;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left: 0px;}
.single #sidebar li {
padding-bottom:15px;}
.single #sidebar li li {
padding:0px;
border:none;}
.single #sidebar img {
margin-bottom:15px;
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
opacity: 0.5;
/* -moz-opacity:0.5; */
position:relative;}
#sidebar .article {
margin:0px;
padding-bottom:0px !important;}
#sidebar .article p {
margin:0;}
#sidebar .article-over {
margin:0;
width:275px;}
#sidebar .article-over .postmetadata {
margin:0;
border-bottom:none;
padding-left:0px!important;}
#sidebar .article h2 {
font-size:21px;
font-weight:normal;
line-height:1.2;
margin-bottom:15px; }
#sidebar .article:hover img {
filter:alpha(opacity=10);
opacity: 0.1;
/* -moz-opacity:0.1; */}
#sidebar #recent-posts li a {
text-decoration:none !important;
border-bottom:1px solid #FF3706;
text-decoration:none;   }
#sidebar #recent-posts li, #sidebar #get-recent-comments li {
margin-bottom:10px;}
#sidebar li li {
padding:0px;
border:none;}
#sidebar .post-date {
font-size:11px;
color:#555;}
#sidebar #get-recent-comments a {
text-decoration:none !important;
font-weight:bold;
border-bottom:1px solid #FF3706;
text-decoration:none;}

.single .article {

padding:0 0 15px 0;}
h1 {
font-size:23px;
font-weight:normal;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom: -15px;
color:F23B35;}

.single h1 {;

font-size:18px;
font-weight:normal;
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left: 160px;
margin-top:15px;}

.single .article h2, .single .article h3, 
.single .article h4, .single .article h5,     .single .article h6 {
margin-left: 160px;
clear: both; }

.single .article h2 {
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-bottom: 13px;
clear: both;}

.single .article h3 {
font-size: 17px;
font-weight: normal;
padding-bottom: 11px;
clear: both;}


.page h2, .page h3, .page h4, .page h5, .page h6 {
 clear: right;}

.page h2 {
font-size: 40px;
padding-bottom:15px;}

.page h3 {
font-size: 17px;
padding-bottom:15px}


.single .article p {
margin-bottom:15px;
margin-left: 160px;}
.article h5 {
float:left;
width:145px;
font-size:11px;
color:#555555;
font-weight:normal;}
.single .postmetadata {
float:left;
width:140px;
margin-top:5px;
font-size:11px;
color:#555;
clear:both;}
.single .postmetadata a {
color:#ff3706 !important;
text-decoration:none !important;}
.single .article .postmetadata {
width:auto;
padding-left: 160px; 
float:none;
padding-bottom:15px;}
.page h1 {
display:none;
font-size:53px;
font-weight:normal;
margin-bottom:15px;
float:left;
width:145px;
margin-top:15px;}
.page .article {
padding-top:15px;
padding-left: 160px;margin-left:-160px;}
#searchform #s {
border:0;
padding:18px 10px 16px;
font-size:23px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
color:#555555;
border:solid 1px #EEE;
margin:15px 0;
width:923px;}
#searchform #s:focus, #searchform #s:hover {
border:solid 1px #ff3706;}

#searchform #searchsubmit {
border:0;
background-color:#eee;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
padding:0 10px;
cursor:pointer;}
#searchform #searchsubmit:hover {
background-color:#ff3706;
color:#FFF;}



#nav {
height:49px;
margin-top:-1px;}
#nav #navright a {
line-height: 49px;
float: right;
padding:0 10px;
text-decoration:none !important;
color:#000 !important;}
#nav #navleft a {
line-height: 49px;
float: left;
padding:0 10px;
text-decoration:none !important;
color:#000 !important;}
.wp-pagenavi a, .wp-pagenavi span {
line-height:25px;
padding:5px 7px;
margin-right:3px;}
.wp-pagenavi .current {
border-bottom:solid 1px #FF3706;}
.wp-pagenavi a {
color:#555;
text-decoration:none !important;}
.wp-pagenavi a:hover {
color:#555;
border-bottom:solid 1px #FF3706;}
.nextpostslink, .previouspostslink {
display:none;}
#footer {
height: 55px;
padding: 25px 430px 0;
border-top:solid 1px #eeeeee;
Margin-bottom:20px;
clear: both;}
#footer a:link, #footer a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
border-bottom:solid 0px #ff3706;}
#footer #copyright {
float:left;}

/* WP image classes */

.entry-content img {
margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;
}
.alignleft, img.alignleft {
margin-right: 1.5em;
display: inline;
float: left;
}
.alignright, img.alignright {
margin-left: 1.5em;
display: inline;
float: right;
}
.aligncenter, img.aligncenter {
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.alignnone, img.alignnone {
/* not sure about this one */
}
.wp-caption {
margin-bottom: 1.5em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5px;
}
.wp-caption img {
border: 0 none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
.wp-caption p.wp-caption-text {
line-height: 1.5;
font-size: 10px;
margin: 0;
font-style: italic;
}
.wp-smiley {
margin: 0 !important;
max-height: 1em;
}
blockquote.left {
margin-right: 20px;
text-align: right;
margin-left: 0;
width: 33%;
float: left;
}
blockquote.right {
margin-left: 20px;
text-align: left;
margin-right: 0;
width: 33%;
float: right;
}

.gallery {
clear: none!important;
float: right;



position:relative;}

.gallery img {


border: 0px!important;}

.entry {
clear:both;}

.photogalleria {
width: 490px;}

div.photogalleria > ul.gallery_list {
margin-left: 75px;}

.page .article .photogalleria {
width:100%!important;}

#twitter_update_list a {
color:#FF3706;
text-decoration:none;
display: inline;}

#twitter_update_list li {
margin-bottom: 25px;}


li#twitter.widget {
padding-bottom:30px;}

.follow {
margin-bottom: 25px;
clear: both;}

.follow a {
background:url("images/larry-shadowed-big.png") no-repeat 6px 3px #fff;
border: 1px solid #FF3706;
color: #FF3706;
text-decoration:none;   
margin-top: 15px;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 10px;
padding-left: 50px;}

.follow a:hover {
background-color:#FF3706;
border: 1px solid #FF3706;  
color: #fff;}

.attachment img {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;}
#nav-below .nav-previous {
display: block;
float: left;
margin-left:160px;}
#nav-below .nav-next {
display: block;
float: right;}
.attachment #comments {
clear: both;}

.attachment #respond {
margin-top: 15px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding `z-index:1000;` and a background color to #top?